# How do you find out if you are inserting duplicate when using Spring Data?

Tags: java, spring, oracle, orm, spring-data-jpa

*Libraries* - Spring-Data-JPA, Java 8, JUnit-4 (for testing)

I have an entity, let us call it `Semaphore`. There are multiple machines trying to create an identical row of `Semaphore`. We only want one of them to succeed. Here is what happens -

1. The `Semaphore` row has a primary key, always 1.
2. Machine A creates the semaphore and saves it to DB using Spring Data `save`
3. Machine B *thinks* it is creating the semaphore as well and calls save but ends up updating it instead, without the client code knowing about it. I can check for `exists` but that does not guarantee anything as both machines could check before either of them has created a record.
4. The machine that won with the insert will clean out the table when finished with processing.

What choices do we have, other than using the Entity Manager directly to see if the entity is new or not? Essentially override the Spring Data save method.

We use Oracle as the DB.

For everyone's ready reference, here is Spring's `SimpleJpaRepository` save method.

```
@Transactional
public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {
    if(this.entityInformation.isNew(entity)) {
        this.em.persist(entity);
        return entity;
    } else {
        return this.em.merge(entity);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have some uniqueness constraint?

Comment: @chrylis edited question. Yes it does, always 1. The problem is `SimpleJpaRepository` silently switches to update if the row exists.

Comment: Ah, so you're relying on the PK. Could you possibly add another field whose sole purpose is uniqueness but that won't get automagically merged?

Comment: @chrylis. Not really. Normally this would be simple - both issue insert, one fails. The other one moves on. This dynamic save is throwing us off.

Comment: What about transaction with `Serializable` isolation level? `@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)`. Annotating your service layer with this should lock the entire table.

Comment: @MikeWojtyna The problem is that Spring Data JPA `save` will merge.

Comment: Then maybe usual optimistic locking? Always try to create new `Semaphore` wtih `@Version` annotated field set to 0. When another thread updates the `Semaphore`, it automatically checks against the versioned field. If it's not equal to zero, then optimistic locking exception should be thrown.

Comment: We are using Optimistic locking, but optimistic locking will not work in this case, because the second (loser) execution will first check for exists, and if so call merge.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but shouldn't merge throw exception when versions don't match? Let's think about following scenario: 1. There's always a semaphore entity (waiting to be "obtained") with version set to 0; 2. Two concurrent transactions performs save with version 0; 3. The first one wins, and thus version is automatically increased by 1; 4. The second won throws optimistic exception (because now version is 1, not 0); 5. When first thread ends, it deletes and recreates the semaphore in a single transaction (so the version is 0 again).

Comment: I saw @MikeWojtyna's answer right after I posted my answer, optimistic locking works exactly like he explained. Unless you are refreshing the entity after saving it should work fine, since both concurrent transactions have the same version, only one will succeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what we do to get around this problem.

1. Do *NOT* use Sprint Data's `save` at the outset.
2. Use the `@Version` tag on a `Long version` filed to version for optimistic locking.
3. Use standard Spring Data `findById` to look for record. If one is found we go to updating it. If the update fails, we know this machine lost it's bid, so it gives up.
4. If no record is found, use JPA `persist` to insert first. If persist fails, we know this machine lost it's bid, so it gives up.
5. The whole thing is wrapped in an `@Transactional` annotation.
6. If we are here and there have been no exceptions, we know we have a winner. It goes ahead and processes.

Thanks all for your help!

Answer (score 1):

What you need is Optimistic locking, you can accomplish that with a version field annotated with `@Version` in your `@Entity` class.

E.g.

```
@Version
private Long version;
```

Comment: Optimistic locking does not work out of the box, because as I explained above Spring data _does_ refresh before save.